# Weird custom function output in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with Wordpress. I am running this function:

```
function name($text = '', $relative = false, $icon = true) {

echo $text;
echo $relative;
echo $icon;

}
```

and the output of it is just "1" (one). How is it possible? Shouldn't be 3 lines of code (3 answers)? I am using apache 2.4, php 5.4.1 and wordpress 3.4 beta 3 on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add wrapper dummies and line breaks to each echo, you'll find why it is showing just "1":

```
function name($text = '', $relative = false, $icon = true) {

echo "text:".$text.";<br>";
echo "relative:".$relative.";<br>";
echo "icon:".$icon.";<br>";

}

name();
```

outputs :

```
text:;
relative:;
icon:1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats correct.

```
<?php
$text='';
$relative=false;
$icon=true;

echo $text;
echo $relative;
echo $icon;

?>
```

First one is null, second one is false which is treated as 0 which is outputed as null. The last one is true, which is 1. Wich makes the output 1.

As shown here:

```
1
```

(output of above script)

Comment: As in not outputting anything (null). Not literally null.